# How can I change the cursor across an entire java application?

Tags: java, image, swing, dialog, cursor

I am creating a custom cursor in my java application using the following code:

```
this.setCursor(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createCustomCursor(
            Utilities.getImage("images\\mouse_pointer.png", false), 
            new Point(0, 0), 
            "cursor"));
```

"this" refers to a class that extends JFrame. The cursor changes as expected using this code, but whenever I open a new modal dialog the cursor returns to it's default state. I tried changing the cursor of each new dialog, but this only works if I am hovering over the dialog; Once I leave the dialog's area the cursor returns to it's original state again. Does anybody know why this is happening or of a way to change the cursor across an entire application? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Is your application losing focus when you see the cursor icon change? Or is this when you are not hovering over area covered by your application windows?

Comment: @thatidiotguy It is when a new JDialog is created and I am not hovering over it. Even if I am hovering over the initial JFrame the cursor returns to it's normal state. Once the new JDialog (modal) is disposed the cursor returns to it's custom state and all is well.

Comment: simply set the cursor of the `JDialog` as well... worked for me

Comment: beware: users might get annoyed if you change their default cursors ...

Comment: @DavidKroukamp This works only if the user hovers over the JDialog; The second you leave the JDialog's area the cursor returns to normal. Is this expected behavior?

Comment: @user1761022 yes, changing the cursor for your frame does not effect the cursor of `JDialog`s, this has to be set separately as for the exact reason i cannot say, but most likely something to do with components inhering top level container cursor, unless it is a top level container itself ...

Comment: @DavidKroukamp OK that makes sense, but why does the cursor return to normal when I leave the JDialog, even if I am then hovering over the original JFrame?

Comment: @user1761022 looking at my code I also had to reset the cursor for my frame when recalling it. I think this also has to do with : when new dialog is created Java translates call to reset cursor for entire app, however it does not keep this information, and when `JDialog` is disposed the original cursor is kept. I don't think its a bug, its more more likely that because applications may only have a single cursor (at a time), Java designers did add features which takes care of resetting cursors etc across multiple containers to previous instances.